# Two conditions in if else using && javascript for drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

So i am trying to get the alert to come out when i have 2 image with id "drag1" and "drag2" inside droppable space together but the if else condition i used using && seems to not work.

Javascript:

```
                $("#drag1").draggable();
                $("#drag2").draggable();

                $(".drop").droppable({
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                        if((id === "drag1") && (id === "drag2")) {
                           alert("ok"); 
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Html:

```
<img id="drag1" draggable="true" src="images/equation1_3.png">
<img  id="drag2" draggable="true" src="images/equation1_2.png">

<div class="drop"> drop here!! </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element has one `id`. You can use selector `#drag1, #drag2` passed to `jQuery()` with `context` set to `.drop` and check `.length` of object is `2`

```
if ($("#drag1, #drag2", $(".drop")).length === 2) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: what if i have 2 droppable box called .drop and .drop1 and i need drag1 to be in both droppable box, how do i check for that since i can only do this condition on a specific box

Answer (score 0):

your condition seems incorrect

```
if((id === "drag1") && (id === "drag2"))
```

If the value of `id` is "drag1", then the second condition is already false and vice versa. `True` `&&` (AND) `false` will always yield `false`. You should probably have used OR